# Solr group.facet=true will not return facet counts

Tags: solr

As the title states, I can't get facet values or counts to return when using the group.facet=true parameter.  group.truncate appears to return the correct values, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I started with the Solr 4 alpha, then Beta, and I'm now working on the nightly build from 9/5/2012.

I'm grouping by a single value field. The fields I am faceting on are a mix of single and multi value fields. I've simplified my query here MyFacetField represents a single value field.

Here are the grouping parameters:

```
group.field=GroupField
group.ngroups=true
group.facet=true
group=true
```

Facet set up like this:

```
f.MyFacetField.facet.limit=-1
f.MyFacetField.facet.mincount=1
f.MyFacetField.facet.sort=false
facet.field=MyFacetField
facet=true
```

Match all documents:

```
q:*:*
```

Again, my problems is:
When I specify group.facet=true I get the list of facet fields I specified in the request paramaters with no values and no counts.

WHen I specify group.facet=false (or leave the parameter out) I get facet values and counts for the ungrouped result set as expected.

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) this feature is included in solr4.

Comment: It's a bug, the patch is here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3956

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the issue was in this parameter.

```
f.MyFacetField.facet.limit=-1
```

When limit is set to -1 (all) and group.facet=true, facet values and their respective counts are not returned by solr.  I'm not sure if this is intended behavior, or not.  This doesn't appear to be a requirement of truncate or of faceting in general with group.facet=false.